# Сравнить элементы списков Java

Tags: java, классы, list

Необходимо сравнить набор коробок. Имеется класс, задающий параметры коробки (высота, ширина, длина):

```
public class Box {
public int h;
public int w;
public int l;

public Box(int h, int w, int l) {
    this.h = h;
    this.w = w;
    this.l = l;
}
```

Вопрос в том, как мне реализовать функцию. То есть входными данными должен быть набор коробок в виде списка? Напирмер:

```
public static List<Box> checkFit(List<Box> listofboxes) { ...
```

Либо же сами коробки:

```
public static List<Box> checkFit(Box box1, Box box2) { ...
```

Comment: это у тебя в каждом листе по одной коробке? или как?

Comment: да, отдельный список - отдельная коробка с собственной высотой, шириной и длиной. если возможно реализовать проще или по-другому, то тоже буду рад ответу

Comment: Уже наступил Новый год, но продолжается путаница со списками _коробок_ и списками _параметров коробок_.  На вопрос, как сравнить величины коробок, ответ такой: как вам угодно, так как могут быть разные варианты: строгое сопоставление ширины, длины, высоты одной коробки соответственно с шириной, длиной, высотой другой коробки, вариант, когда можно коробку вращать вокруг одной оси, или вокруг всех трех.  Также непонятно, что имеется в виду под "подходит"/"не подходит" - строго меньше по всем трем параметрам, или хотя бы по двум.

Comment: _отдельный список - отдельная коробка с собственной высотой, шириной и длиной._  -- значит надо сравнивать *коробки*, а не их списки: `public static Result checkFit(Box box1, Box box2)',  где класс должен называться `Box`, чтобы не сбивать с толку ненужным множественным числом.

Comment: отредактировал вопрос, все пояснил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

создай в классе метод, который по нужной логике высчитывает параметр для сравнения, например сложение

```
int result() {
        return h + w + l;
    }
```

в методе check у каждой коробки вызвать метод result и сравнить его

```
int compareResult =  Integer.compare(box1.get(0).result()
                ,box2.get(0).result());
```

и не надо плодить много return, создай переменную типа Rusult,
в которую запишешь результат if блоков и потом вернёшь её.

ты можешь сравнивать значение любого поля... так думаю будет понятней

```
int number = new Box(11,32,52).h;
        System.out.println(number); // 11

        System.out.println(number>100); //false
```

Comment: нужно сравнивать величины коробок, а не считать параметр для сравнения

Comment: что в твоём понимании величина коробки?

Comment: не величина, а величины (длина, ширина, высота) мы сравниваем их у первой и второй коробки

Comment: ну тогда вместо box1.get(0).result() пиши box1.get(0).h или что надо сравнить